# Question regarding a proof in the classification theorem of the isometries of the hyperbolic plane

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, isometry

The following extract is from the proof of the classification theorem of the isometries of the hyperbolic plane from the book *Fuchsian groups* by *Svetlana Katok* (pages 8 to 10).

> For an isometry $f$ we found that $$f(z) = z \qquad \text{or} \qquad
> f(z) = -\bar{z}$$ for $z \in \mathbb{H} := \{z \in \mathbb{C} :
> \mathrm{Im}(z) > 0\}$. Now the author concludes that only one equation can hold for all $z \in \mathbb{H}$ by the continuity of an isometry.

I do not quite see this. First of all, I think continuity is meant with respect to the hyperbolic metric $\rho$ (i.e. the one given by the Riemannian metric). Then continuity is obvious since each isometry is Lipschitz continuous. However, I do not see why this should imply that only one equation holds.

**Edit.** Thanks to reuns I figured out the main issue: I have to show that a function which is continuous with respect to the hyperbolic metric is also continuous with respect to the standard metric. However this is clear since the metric topology generated by the hyperbolic distance function is the same as the original topology on $\mathbb{H}$.

Comment: What is your question ? The complex analytic isometries $\mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{H}$ are the Möbius transformations $z\mapsto \frac{az+b}{cz+d}, (a,b,c,d) \in \mathbb{R}^4, ad-bc = 1$ and the real-analytic ones include $z\mapsto \frac{ -a \overline{z}+b}{ - c\overline{z}+d}$. One possible proof is with [Schwarz's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma).

Comment: @reuns In the proof of the statement you gave we have that $f(z) = z$ or $f(z) = - \bar{z}$ POINTWISE for $z \in \mathbb{H}$. Now to conclude, the author says that due to the continuity of an isometry, either $f(z) = z$ or $f(z) = - \bar{z}$ FOR ALL $z \in \mathbb{H}$. The question is, that I do not quite see how to deduce this from the continuity of an isometry.

Comment: ... You have a function such that for every $z$, $f(z) \in \{z,-\overline{z}\}$. If $f$ is assumed continuous then automatically $f$ is $z \mapsto z$ or $z \mapsto -\overline{z}$. Isn't this obvious ? Maybe you don't see that a function is continuous for the hyperbolic metric implies it is continuous for the usual topology on $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}^2$ (ie. locally the hyperbolic plane is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{H}$)

Comment: @reuns The problem is, that $f$ is continuous with respect to the hyperbolic metric $\rho$. I tried to show that it is also continuous with respect to the standard metric $|\cdot|$, but I failed. Yes...exactly I do not see this.

Comment: Locally $y$ is almost constant $\approx c$ so $\frac{dx^2+dy^2}{y^2}$ is not very different to $\frac{dx^2+dy^2}{c^2}$. And the difference in topology is at the boundary of $\mathbb{H}$ : where $y$ is very small or very large. For the euclidean metric $i \infty$ is very far to $10^3 i$ but not in the hyperbolic metric, and $0$ is very close to $10^{-3} i$, but not in the hyperbolic metric.